# Any way to turn off the Catalina login after wake?

Tags: sleep-wake, catalina, login

So I get that Catalina was supposed to be more secure and protect your privacy yadda yadda but my computer is at home behind a locked door and a doorman, I don't need to enter my login password every time the Mac wakes up from sleep. The Security and Privacy setting to require login after sleep or screen saver is turned off and indeed when I interrupt the screen saver it gets me back to the computer, but if I leave it for too long and the screen saver goes to black and the computer sleeps, it always requires a login when woken up. This was *never* the case prior to Catalina. Is there anything I can do to disable it? The interwebs have failed me in my search.

Comment: You could prevent your computer from sleeping in System Preferences -> Energy Saver by setting the "Turn display off after" slider to never. This would mean you would just have your screensaver on forever. Would that help you?

Comment: Well, that kind of defeats the purpose of energy saver. Its an iMac 5K so does consume a fair amount of energy. I have a hot corner to turn off the screen so I guess that would help but I'd live with logging in if I didn't have to make the thing never sleep. There must have been something they did in Catalina to change this and there must have been a reason (I'm assuming security but who knows). It almost feels like this just snuck in there.